# Erro ao instanciar objeto [não definido]

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Estava fazendo um exercício simples, mas na hora de utilizar o objeto aparece como não definido...

```
  class Aluno{
        constructor(paramNome, paramNot1, paramNot2) {
            this.nome = paramNome;
            this.nota1 = paramNot1;
            this.nota2 = paramNot2;
        }

        calcularMedia = (nota1,nota2)=>(nota1+nota2)/2;
        imprimirBoletin = ()=>console.log(`${this.nome}teve a media de ${this.calcularMedia(this.nota1,this.nota2)} `);
    }
```

Em outro arquivo na mesma pasta

```
const aluno = new Aluno('Felipe',5,5);
console.log(aluno.imprimirBoletin());
```

> **ERRO :ReferenceError: Aluno is not defined**
>       at Object. (c:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\exercicios de js\exercicio03\exercicio03.js:1:77)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.293 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando instanciar um objeto que não foi importado para o módulo, sua classe não está visível, pois é um arquivo externo.

O seu módulo deve conter: require("./"seu-arquivo.js")

Referências: http://nodebr.com/como-funciona-a-funcao-require-do-node-js/